# Android Mapview not loading tiles on HTC Desire?

Tags: android-mapview, android

I have an app on the android market, which uses the mapview to display some locations. This works fine on all the devices i have tested it on. After having it on the market for a while, i see several people reporting a problem.

The mapview does not seam to display/load the tiles on the map, and only displays the gray grid. All the people reporting this, are using a HTC Desire/Desire Z/Desire HD.

I have searched for this problem, and seen many having problems with their mapview, and they often have a HTC desire, but i have not found any mention of it being caused by the Desire phone.

Does anyone have a clue to why people with Desire phones are having problems with the mapview, when it works fine for others?

Comment: Just a thought.. Did you test the released application on different devices, or did you test the dev version? Only thing I can think of that might cause the problem is if the maps api key was obtained using the debug certificate, in which case the map will not load in the released app.

Comment: The released version has been tested on several devices and there are several hundred active installs from the market that seams to work fine. So the majority of the users are not having any problems.

Comment: I can also see that the phone that has most installs is the HTC desire, so most of them must have it working. It might just be a coincidence that it is only people with Desire phones who report the problem?

Comment: Seems odd that it should be restricted to just a problem with Desire phones, especially since it's not just one version of Desire but all three. If you give me the name of the app I'll be happy to test it out for you.

Comment: The app is called "Top Attraktioner" (I can see you'r from DTU, so you should be able to understand it).

Comment: Same problem here on a HTC Hero running 2.2.1. The only thing I can think of that is wrong is the maps api key. I just released an app myself using the Google MapView activity, and have the exact same problem if I use the wrong api key for the release build.

Comment: I am quite sure that i have used the correct key, and i wonder why it works on most deviced, and not others. If the key was wrond, shouldn't it fail on all devices?

Comment: I agree, it should. Provided the key is correct - see http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html.

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem on my app. It is failing on HTC Legend & Hero only, still investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an update to the application, where i created a new maps api key, and it is working now.

I am not sure what caused the problem before, but i think they may have changed the type of key you have to submit for the maps key.
I have an old file where i had written a SHA1 Certificate fingerprint of the application and i am quite sure that it is the one i used to get the old maps api key. Maybe they changed something along the way, that caused it to fail on most phones?

Anyway, creating a new maps key from an MD5 Certificate fingerprint fixed it on every phone i have tested with.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded your application and tested it on my HTC Desire with MIUI, and as you said the mapview is not loading the tiles on the map.
FYI the application gives the following error:

```
IOException processing: 26
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Here you can find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android) with the same problem, which seems related to the maps key. 
As I said my Desire uses MIUI v1.10.28, with gingerbread, so the problem shouldn't be related to HTC's sense ROM... as it has been some time since you posted your question, do you have more information of the devices in which your application doesn't work?

Comment: I have tested it on several devices. The ones i have tried where it does not work are: Samsung Galaxy 1, LG Optimus 2x, HTC Legend and HTC Incredile S. Actually, the only one I have right now that works, is the Google Nexus one. But most of the users of my app don't seem to have the problem, while others do?

Comment: Maybe the second proposed fix has something to do with your problem? : http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2010/android-map-tiles-not-loading-and-possible-fixes/

Comment: I have just tried that, and it changed nothing. I also tried to generate a new map API key, but i no longer have access to the account that the app is published from, so i am not able to generate a new key at the moment.