# Android maps key not working empty tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google map signed api key errors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android)

I've really tried every possible solution I could find.. I'm close to pulling out all my hair doing something I've done a million times before, but it's just not working, whatever I try! I get the following log when running an exported .apk on a device:

```
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068): IOException processing: 26
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
10-23 16:39:31.504: W/System.err(14068):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

I've done the following (as so many others):

1. Created a new certificate (directly in the terminal and also from
   Eclipse)
2. Generated MD5 and pasted into google api key web page (using both my own and an actual publishers google account, doesn't matter
3. Used the api key for the map view in the layout xml file
4. Setting debuggable = false
5. including the lib inside the application tags
6. Added all the necessary permissions
7. Checked that the maps app work correctly

Everything works flawless when running in debug-mode, so what am I missing during the export? I choose the projekt, keystore file, enter password and save file. That's it! (That's what I've always done and it's always worked before)

Really, I've tried everything I've found, but I STILL get the error above! Now, from your experience: What possible setup can cause the error above so consistently?

Of course, it IS the keystore file/api key in some way, but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

seems like this: 
[Google map signed api key errors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android)

is the exact same problem you are facing. It says that with

> debuggable = false

set, you need to install your apk from the store. And only in that case the tiles will be displayed. Is that solving your problem?

Comment: I want to export an app for beta testing with the maps working, should I use the debug.keystore for that? I've always signed the .apk files for beta testing before.

Comment: if you release them in the playstore it should work with a signed key. but according to the other thread, you can't run your apk from eclipse with a signed key (at least you will get the tiles problem).

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a keystore-related issue. Here's how I solved MY problem.

albrechtATnetzfactor pointed out a correct solution for publishing an app to GPlay, but I wanted to release a BETA.

Just choose the debug.keystore and set debuggable=true when exporting an APK for BETA TESTING.

I spent the whole afternoon on this, hating Android more for every day...

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `Map key` obtained with the certificate you sign the application?

Comment: 1. Generate cert (release.keystore)
2. -keytool -list bla bla => MD5
3. Use MD5 on google site
4. Use obtained api key in maps view xml layout
5. Export using same cert (release.keystore)

Comment: you create a certificate and with it you sign your application. Then you need to go to the developer site and retrive the specific map api key for the certificate.

Comment: in the layout did you put the correct key?