# MapView not showing data

Tags: android

I have created the simple `MapView` example in `android`, but it is not displaying anything in the emulator

Logcat Datails are:

```
01-30 10:24:53.976: W/System.err(1033): IOException processing: 26
01-30 10:24:53.983: W/System.err(1033): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
01-30 10:24:54.003: W/System.err(1033):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
01-30 10:24:54.020: W/System.err(1033):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
01-30 10:24:54.022: W/System.err(1033):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
01-30 10:24:54.022: W/System.err(1033):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
01-30 10:24:54.022: W/System.err(1033):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
01-30 10:24:54.032: W/System.err(1033):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-30 10:24:54.263: W/Trace(1033): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 10:24:54.263: W/Trace(1033): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 10:24:54.343: W/Trace(1033): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think the map API key is wrong. Try regenerating the key:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey