# WebView doesn't work after generate APK [React-Native]

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-ios

i Used Webview to integration with PayPal:
sample of the code:

```
<Modal
                    animationType={"fade"}
                    transparent={false}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        alert("Modal has been closed")
                    }}
                    >
                        <WebView
                            source={ require('./PayPalIntegration.html')}
                            style={{flex: 10, width: width, height: height, margin: 20, alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 10,}}onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({ modalVisible: false})
                        }}>
                            <Text>
                                X Close
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Modal>
```

It works when i use iOS emulator from Xcode, work on AndroidStudio's AVD manager, and also works when i use `react-native run-android` direct to my device.
But after generated APK and installed it, i see only the `Modal` and the `WebView` isn't working.

I did several things to try to fix this:

1. I check the configurations of the proguard and according to other posts here and it was FALSE already, according to [web view not loading page after exporting to signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142027/web-view-not-loading-page-after-exporting-to-signed-apk)
2. I added `-keepattributes JavascriptInterface` according to [JavascriptInterface on Android dont work with APK in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549706/javascriptinterface-on-android-dont-work-with-apk-in-release-mode)

I must say that i can check it only on ANDROID because i can only generate APK (do not have apple's developer account)

Comment: Help someone...?

Comment: Hello there, I know this is old but I posted an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544869/2225316. The answer there is related to this one and will work for your use case.

Comment: @BoomerRogers Thanks! It is an old post but still exist in the same old project. I'll try to fix it with your solution and will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" under application tag in AndroidManifest.xml. It should look like below snippet.

```
<application
      .........
      .........
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      .........
```