# Cannot display Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create my first Google Maps in Android using an emulator in Eclipse with no success. All I get for the map is a gray tiled screen that I can zoom but there is no map there. Below is my `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.herb2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.herb2.Herb2Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my key is not shown here" />

</manifest>
```

Below is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitude_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latitude: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longitude_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Longitude: " />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapvw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="my key is not shown here"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally below is my java source:

```
public class Herb2Activity extends MapActivity {

    private TextView latitudeView;
    private TextView longitudeView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GeoPoint point;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_herb2);
        latitudeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_view);
        longitudeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_view);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapvw);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                3600, 1000, new LocationListener() {

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                        if (loc != null) {
                            int lt = (int) (loc.getLatitude());
                            int lg = (int) (loc.getLongitude());
                            latitudeView.setText("Latitude is: "
                                    + String.valueOf(lt));
                            longitudeView.setText("Longitude is: "
                                    + String.valueOf(lg));
                            int latit = (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6);
                            int longit = (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6);
                            point = new GeoPoint(latit, longit);
                            mapController.animateTo(point);
                            mapController.setZoom(15);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am suspecting it may have something to do with my API key which I generated from Google.  I provided the SHA1 certificate fingerprints to generate my key. I added at the end of the key my package name which is `com.example.herb2` as shown above. I also made sure I was using a Google API device as my emulator. I assume the MD5 fingerprint is used for production. I will appreciate any help on why my map shows nothing but gray.

Comment: Most likely there's a problem with your API key. Does your logcat say anything regarding authorization failure?

Comment: You should get something like: System:err - IOException: Server returned 3 in your logcat if the map API key is wrong.

Comment: I had no errors in the logcat, just warnings.  I suspect it is the api key also.  I followed the instructions for generating the key and I used the SHA1 fingerprint and not the MD5 fingerprint.  When entering my fingerprint I followed it with a semicolon and my package name which was "com.example.herb2" as you can see above.  Do you think I should just generate another key?

Comment: On checking again I did get warnings in the logcat such as IOException processing: 26; then java.io.IOException:Server returned" 3 then at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.comgoogle.googlenav.map.BaseTitleRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)  Does anyone know what these mean?

Comment: I think your Google API had problem. You should get it again.

Comment: If I am running on an emulator do I use the MD5 fingerprint or the SHA1 fingerprint to get my key?  I am following an example in a book and I don't which device they are referring to when obtaining a key.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Google map signed api key errors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android/8989312#8989312)?

It most probably is that you're using a signed key instead of a debug key.

Comment: How do I know if I am using a signed key instead of a debug key?  I used the SHA1 fingerprint instead of the MD5 fingerprint.

Comment: The procedure for generating a signed key is different from a debug key. Check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: I followed the instructions set forth by Google and redid the creation of my signature fingerprint several times and it always generates the same SHA1 value.  I guess I will just create another api key and see what happens.  This is very frustrating as it shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: I agree. Start afresh. It's very simple and straightforward.

Comment: I started over and got a new api key using my SHA1 fingerprint and I still get a gray screen.  I really don't what to do next.  I am getting the IOException processing: 26 warning and the java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3 warning as usual.  I don't know if that means the api key is bad or what.  I really want to make my website into an app but at the rate I am going I ready to throw in the towel and go to IOS instead.

Comment: you're not using the debug key. if you want to be sure, just launch it to the market and test it out. You can always deactivate it after you're doing live testing.

Comment: OK. First I copied my file debug.keystore from my android subdirectory under my users directory to the C: drive.  Then I entered the following command:  keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:debug.keystore" -storepass android - keypass android.  Then I copied the SHA1 fingerprint to create my api key for an android installation in Google API Console.  I put this api key into my program.  So how do I know whether I am using a debug key or not?  I am only getting one key back so where did I go wrong?