# Link to obtain Google Map Key is not available

Tags: android, google-maps

I have extracted `MD5 fingerprint` .Now I want to obtain the `Google Map key` but link is not working. I found http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html in `Wei-Meng lee`book `Beginnining Android 4 Application Development` latest publication to get the `Google Map key`.Can anyone update the new link to get the `Google Map key`. I googled it but not able to find it.

Comment: u need sha key and go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1#project:557155832266

Comment: go to there https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: @Monica Thanx...is `MD5 fingerprint` no more useful. and Sha1 key is only the way to get `Google Map key` from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [link...](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)and go to **Services** turn on the service named **Google Maps Android API v2**,

then go to **API Access**

Now Click on **Create New Android Key**

after that Paste your SHA1 key ; and your project's package name

for ex: **YOUR_SHA1_KEY;com.example.xyz**

And lastly click on **create**.It will generate your google map key for you.

Comment: can u update ur ans with detail explain how to get the Google Map key using this link.Step by step

Comment: @shakeeb-shaheen check this out.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is screen shot for creating map key

[image]

> make sure u hv this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to refer `Google official` [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

You can also refer `step by step process` how to generate **google map api key** and used using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398159/generate-google-map-key-for-android-step-by-step) So question.

If you are reading careful then **100%** your problem is solve.

If any query then put comment.**Happy coding.**

Comment: thnx for fast reply..There no problem now. +1