# Google Maps application not showing the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

when I run my applicationn (google-map application), I don't see the map. I just see a white screen (like in the photo below).

#### mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.williamroma.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

          <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

      <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

#### activity

```
package com.williamroma.example;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the screen that i see, i want to see the map like in this tuotiral http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/
[image]

#### layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCyk2MVC5Fyl7HIB3iHlPgyRqvOF-VXYJw"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### edit

i got these message in orange color in logcat

```
03-31 11:31:16.140: I/Process(1787): Sending signal. PID: 1787 SIG: 9
03-31 11:31:40.940: I/MapActivity(1832): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
03-31 11:31:40.940: E/MapActivity(1832): Couldn't get connection factory client
03-31 11:31:41.011: D/dalvikvm(1832): GC_CONCURRENT freed 170K, 4% free 9316K/9607K, paused 8ms+6ms
03-31 11:31:41.011: W/CursorWrapperInner(1832): Cursor finalized without prior close()
03-31 11:31:41.011: W/CursorWrapperInner(1832): Cursor finalized without prior close()
03-31 11:31:41.020: D/gralloc_goldfish(1832): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-31 11:31:42.470: W/System.err(1832): IOException processing: 26
03-31 11:31:42.470: W/System.err(1832): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
03-31 11:31:42.490: W/System.err(1832):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
03-31 11:31:42.490: W/System.err(1832):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
03-31 11:31:42.500: W/System.err(1832):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
03-31 11:31:42.500: W/System.err(1832):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
03-31 11:31:42.520: W/System.err(1832):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
03-31 11:31:42.520: W/System.err(1832):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: do you mind to show your activity layout? and how did you managed to get a key for google map api v1?

Comment: Google Maps Android v1 which is deprecated move to [Google Map V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) and refer [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html) for good tutorial using Google Map v2

Comment: @EmilAdz i add my layout

Comment: I suppose the problem is with your API key.

Comment: i am sure that the key is right, i edit the quesiton

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli i am suing `Google Maps Android API v2` key with android emulator `google api 15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of it your code looks ok for Google Map API V1. So there must be some problem with your key. for what I know if it's a new generated key then Google doesn't provide keys for Google Map API V1, so it must be a key for Google Map API V2 and that's the reason it doesn't work.

if you would like to change you application implementation to Google Maps API V2, you can use this guide I wrote with the steps to do so:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: i don't want to change the code, i want to correct it, please i hate fragments and don't know who to work with it, the key is right , i used `Google Maps Android API v2`

Comment: look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android

Comment: maybe you created a release key as described in this post and that's the reason you don't see a map.

Comment: the answer there sends me to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start and i have already read each line in this link

Comment: i created the key using this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/ , i just added -v to get SHA1 not MD5 certificate fingerprint

Comment: was i created the key successfully using that way ?

Comment: No you weren't, you created a key for Google Map API V2, and it won't work with API V1.

Comment: yes ofc i created the key from `Google Maps Android API v2`, i ment that i created the SHA1 fingerprint using that link

Comment: please y u keep saying `api v1` i have never come across it and i did not mention it

Comment: you don't understand: if you used SHA1 fingerprint to create your key, then you created it for Google Map API V2 because for Google Map API V1 MD5 fingerprint was used. I don't think you can create this key today as it was deprecated. So the key you have won't work with the code you written.

Comment: i create my key using SHa1 NOT md5

Comment: right. So you created a key for Google Map V2, while you use V1 in your code. It won't work.

Comment: I can't help you more then that... change your code. leave the old Google Map API V1 and move to the new one. It's not that hard, just follow the guide.

Comment: how did u know that i user `v1` in my code? please would u change it to `v2` but tell me please where is the `v1` in my code

Comment: You are using MapView and MapActivity which are Google Map API V1 objects. You can look at my 10 steps guide and do it your self : )

Comment: i cant extend `FragmentActivity` , why please?

Comment: OMG i updated the ADB then the SDK then create the key and now change to V2, i am testing the code in `google api 15` which i download it yesterday

Comment: if you are using api 15 and don't intent to support early versions sdk's then you can change you activity to be a simple Activity and instead of using SupportMapFragment in your xml you can use MapFragment.

Comment: you help me a lot, i will start a new question , because i change to v2 and i have problems , i will put the link for my new question here, thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729330/android-google-map-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem with legal key.I obtained it in 10th of March and google closed key V1 generator in 18th of March and told that apps with V1 will continue to operate normally.All of this time until yesterday my app worked fine but today i see a blank page.