# android google map Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps

here we go ,removed the fat from the question and now i will add what ever you want pleaes hurry

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few problems:

**1.** Change the package name in those lines:

```
 <permission
    android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

and:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

from: `your.application.package` to: `com.williamroma.example`.

**2.** Remove this:

```
 <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

**3.** and remove this from the bottom:

```
 <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

you already have it in the upper permissions.

but it looks that your problem is because you didn't referencing the Google library correctly.
Go over the `first three steps` of my guide again.

**Update:**

check that you have the selected (red) libraries under your dependencies library of your project (green).

[image]

Comment: sorry for mistakes in the names , after your edits i got exceptions that i post in the question again , pplease give me your guide again

Comment: i am using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: i did those 3 steops before you give me the link, really , the only change is that you used android 4.1 , i used google api 15

Comment: show a screen shot of you dependecies library in your project.

Comment: after adding `support libaray` i got this error when importing (like you said in ur blog) , i give u the image

Comment: in the dependence i just have android support v4, i don't have google play service, i try to add it as u said in ur blog but i can't , please see the image i added to the question , i was able to add it before but after i add `suport android library` like you said , i couldn't

Comment: if you already added to support library to you workspace you can't added it again, it a normal behavior. follow now the next steps to add a reference from the project in your workspace to your map project. you can try to restart eclipse and check dependencies folder again after. this helped me once.

Comment: i want to go from property to add reference , but i got empty screen because i haven't add that google play service because as i told you the image in the question , please please see the image in my question , there is the wrong, please tell me how to solve it

Comment: i am from syria, if i didn't show up after 15 mins that means the electricity is gone, pelase hurry

Comment: if you already added to support library to you workspace you can't added it again, it a normal behavior. it not a problem if you look in your workspace project list you should see there the google-play-services-lib

Comment: i accept ur anwer, thanks for help , i will keep searching for this problems

Comment: in the future don't ever delete the content of your question. this way the answers are loosing context with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add android Private Libraries to:

```
Project
  => Properties
     => Java build path
        => Order and Export
           => Select Android Private Libraries
```