# Android Maps v2 Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, api-key

I have a problem. I am getting a blank google map. I tried everything around the net. But nothing seems to solve this issue. I have pasted the logcat below. I have tried both debug key and release key. But both are not working. The map is not working. I just get a grey background with Google written below :(  Please help

```
09-04 12:29:57.037: E/MapActivity(9569): Couldn't get connection factory client
09-04 12:29:57.067: D/dalvikvm(9569): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 2% free 9295K/9464K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
09-04 12:29:57.637: W/System.err(9569): IOException processing: 26
09-04 12:29:57.637: W/System.err(9569): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
09-04 12:29:57.647: W/System.err(9569):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
09-04 12:29:57.647: W/System.err(9569):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
09-04 12:29:57.657: W/System.err(9569):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
09-04 12:29:57.657: W/System.err(9569):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
09-04 12:29:57.657: W/System.err(9569):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
09-04 12:29:57.657: W/System.err(9569):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textlat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textlong"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="API Key"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rrj.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <permission
    android:name="com.rrj.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.rrj.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.rrj.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="API_KEY"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[UPDATE]: I tried generating the sha1fingerprint again. I observed that the signature algorithm used is SHA256withRSA where as the example in the [google dev site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information) show SHA1withRSA could this be causing any problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to hide it or not, but your API_KEY in your meta tag in the manifest actually needs to be your API KEY.

Comment: @kayton I am hiding the API KEY :)

Comment: recreate the API key and uninstall the app try now.

Comment: @Aravinth I tried it. Dint help. I tried with both debug key and release key. But which key should I use when I run it from Eclipse?

Comment: @Droidme refer this one for maps.....  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @Aravinth I have updated the question at the end please have a look

Comment: are you try this one http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/...

Comment: @Aravinth Done the tutorial solved the problem

Comment: if you want upvote my answer also.

Comment: @Aravinth Thank u for the link. The thing I was missing was in the answer tht I have apreoved. Ur link helped me pther ways too. Thank u once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML file you are using pld Google Map API v1.. And in your Manifest file you have wrote code for Google Map V2.. SO just add this in xml replace with old.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and yes also remove

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

from manifest file....

you can refer this also:

[Still Gets "Couldn't get connection factory client" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737960/still-gets-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-error)

[android google map Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729330/android-google-map-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

Answer (score 1):

[Google map v1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/) is deprecated
[check this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for Google map v2.
[Good tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html)

try using `SupportMapFragmentin` your `XML`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

map samples [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2)

Comment: Dint work. I think it has something to do with the API Key :(

Comment: remove line <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> from maniefest and check it again

Comment: also add   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission in your manifest

```
<permission
android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

remove this one

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and check whether you have google play services or not.