# MapActivity :Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use google map for my android application but all i get is grey grids and in logcat it shows error like :

02-11 09:49:56.860: E/MapActivity(979): Couldn't get connection factory client

- I have added permission in manifest to use internet.
- I have used google library.
- I have used Correct Map Api key for android application.
- I am using correct emulator to support google API
  Browser in my emulator is working and connecting to internet but my App is not working **even on android mobile!**

here is my manifest file code :

```
package="com.nawed.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nawed.maps.ShowMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity class :

```
package com.nawed.maps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class ShowMap extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

My XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="MyKey"
/>
```

I have seen other repeated questions but it doesn't worked for me.
**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: ahh, hide your key...

Comment: Refer to this answer. It seems that this is the same issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607494/android-maps-v2-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client