# Android Google Map V2 Display Blank and show only zoom button?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i use the google map v2 and display the multiple marker 
 but first i want  to display the map on the screen 
i put down my all the files here 
is gives only blank i will check it out all but nothing work for me

[image]

> main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.stiptis.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.stiptis.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.stiptis.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
          <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="your api key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }



}
```

Comment: [**This**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/07/google-map-tutorial-android-advance.html) may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably there is a problem with your Maps API Key.
Put this function into your activity, and see what it logs for the correct SHA key:

```
 private void getShaKey() {

 try {
 PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package.name",
 PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
 for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
 md.update(signature.toByteArray());
 Log.v(TAG, "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
 Base64.DEFAULT));
 }
 } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

 }

 }
```

Comment: 04-12 12:49:15.783: E/Google Maps Android API(28634): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.

Comment: Did you sign your app with your debug keystore or an other one? Did you include google play services lib as a library project?

Comment: Make sure the "Google Maps Android API v2", not "Google Maps API v2" is enabled and re-generate the API key if so

Comment: If your map is working properly, than it's fine :)
But the getShaKey() function I wrote in my answer logs the correct key if you run it.

Comment: i got the solution i create new api key with other account now is work thanks

Comment: did you change the "your.package.name" argument? did you debug it? is it a standard android device?

Answer (score 0):

In case you tried the map example from sdk extras, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19436565/874502) helpful.

Comment: It seems that the system flagged you down for posting the same answer twice. Can you elaborate on each of them to make it clearer and more applicable to each question?

Answer (score 0):

There Also the probability to be **name package** problem used for **android key** generation

Answer (score 0):

This prints out the signature and package name that you need to enter in Google Developers Console to generate API key:

```
private void getShaKey() {
    try {
      Activity activity = this; // or getActivity() if the code is in fragment
      String packageName = activity.getPackageName();
      PackageInfo info = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
      for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "KeyHash: " + bytesToHex(digest) + ";" + packageName);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
      int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
      hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
      hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hexChars.length; i += 2) {
      sb.append(hexChars[i]);
      sb.append(hexChars[i + 1]);
      if (i < hexChars.length - 2) {
        sb.append(':');
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Look for KeyHash: in the logs.

This is modification of Analizer's code.