# Maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have made a simple google map in android but the problem is that on running i m only gettin zoom buttons and map is not loading.I have generated api key 3 time.
here is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amal.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

     <!-- The following two permissions are required for location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.amal.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyCh4vRdbH__Dgg7n-3t8TTkhsUVC8CtNKM"/>
        <meta-data 
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

here is xml file
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>`
```

here is class file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(13.05241, 80.25082);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Raj Amal"));
    }}
```

Plz if anyone can help

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964981/android-google-map-v2-display-blank-and-show-only-zoom-button

Comment: Yes i have.I have generated the api key so many times

Comment: Thanks it worked.I generated a new key with different account

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

First of all check that you have googleplayservice library added in your project, Then

Use FragmentActivity. Activity is not from v4 nor from v7 support libraries. This should work:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap googleMap;
```

in onCreate

```
 int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ 

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {             

            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            googleMap = fm.getMap();
}
```

Comment: It is showing that getSupportFragementManager is Undefined for main activity

Comment: Sorry but maps r still not loading.It is only showing zoom buttons