# Two applications (packages) with the same Google Maps ID

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a `Project` that is using `Google Maps v1`. Now I made a kind of clone of that `Application` with a different `package` `name`. Both apps are signed with the same `keystore` file.

Problem: maps are shown on the first `App` and are not seen on the `second`. The error I receive from Google is:

```
System.err  java.io.IOException: Server returned: at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

So is it possible at all to have multiple apps using the same Google Maps v1 API ID as long as they are using the same keystore file?

Comment: Can we see your manifest?

Comment: [Google map signed api key errors in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8989312/1693859)

Comment: Cannot post the whole manifest here, what part of the Manifest exactly you want to see?

Comment: Sam Rad, thank you, I've seen that post before. They say that the map will show when downloaded from Goole Play. Still doesn't sound ok in my case, since the Map is showing for the first App and it is not shown for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I signed both applications with the same key from the keystore.

I was not able to see Maps before because I was creating a new key for the new project.