# Android Google Maps API throwing server returned 3

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to display Google Maps in my android Application. But it is displaying empty grids in when I integrate `Google-Maps-Api` in my application and is showing an error as
`IOException processing: 26` and `java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3`. I also even tried by changing API key but no luck, can anybody please help me out.

Any help is Appreciated

Comment: Please mention with Google API version you are using. Is it Google API-V2?

Comment: check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296467/google-map-signed-api-key-errors-in-android)

Comment: Is APK signed? Did you install support libraries?

Comment: You are trying to use deprecated API that will not work for new apps. Consider switching to Google Maps Android API v2.