# java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3 on Android Google Maps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to embedding Google Maps on my android application, but the API throwing an "IOException:  Server returned: 3", like this question: [Android Google Maps API throwing server returned 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691685/android-google-maps-api-throwing-server-returned-3) with empty grids

I tried to follow these tips:

1. Using Google Maps API v2? Yes and follow this steps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
2. Is APK signed? Signer with debug certificate yet, generate the API KEY right here: https://console.developers.google.com/ and using SHA-1 fingerprint showing in eclipse (preferences -> Android -> Build -> SHA1 Fingerprint)

If anyone can help, i will appreciate

My AndroidManifest.xml:

1. My permissions and features:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <!-- Location -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   <!-- OpenGL for Google Maps -->
   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true" />
   ```
2. Useful details in "application" tag:

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_iconlauncher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/customActionBarTheme"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/api_key_gmaps" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       [...]
   </application>
   ```

In my layout definition:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigationBottom"
    android:apiKey="@string/api_key_gmaps"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google developer docs for Maps V2 is totally misleading... i've struggled all day to get it to work. What worked for me is the following:

In your layout file, instead of MapView element, you should use a fragment element with the "class" attribute set to "com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment" like this: 
Note that i'm using the support libraries because of my min target api which is 8.

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

In your activity, you should get the instance of the map first getting the fragment using the fragmentManager, then casting it to the class you used, and then calling getMap():

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;



public class SelectLojaActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_loja);

    map  = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();

}


}
```

Don't forget to import the google-play-services_lib at [your-android-sdk-folder]/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and add it in your project->properties->android as a library.

!!IMPORTANT!! At least in my case, i've experienced a very annoying problem after adding google-play-services, Eclipse started to run out of memory when trying to compile the project. To solve this problem i had to edit eclipse.ini inside the eclipse folder, and raise the amount of memory it uses:

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

Increase the last two values something like -Xms512m and -Xmx1024m, restart eclipse, increase the values incrementaly until the memory heap size problem goes away.
Hope it helps...